# What alternative syntaxes are there for expressing XML?

Tags: xml, text, syntax, editing, sox

What human-readable and human-editable syntaxes exist that can be automatically converted to and from XML with no loss of expressivity. In other words, an updated version of [this list](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-syntax/index.html). The three syntaxes mentioned there are:

- [SOX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Outline_XML)
- PYX
- SLiP

Are there others? (This isn't about alternatives *to* XML, like JSON, but simply easier ways for humans to maintain XML files using a text editor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some more answers:

- [CompactXML](http://packages.python.org/compactxml/) - one alternative general purpose XML syntax, looks fairly sensible
- [SLAX](http://code.google.com/p/libslax/) - an alternative syntax for XSL. Looks like an odd hybrid of JavaScript, CSS, and...I'm not sure.
- [RELAX NG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELAX_NG) - a schema language for XML (like XSL), with a compact alternative syntax.

And some useful links:

- [XSugar](http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/papers/xsugar/journal.pdf) - interesting paper about the problem
- [XFlat](http://www.unidex.com/overview.htm#The%20XFlat%20Language) - a general tool for converting between definable "flat" formats and XML. (So not a particular syntax)
- [XSCS](http://dret.net/netdret/docs/wilde-tikrep166.pdf) - a paper describing something very similar to CompactXML above. I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a good way to simply view and make small tweaks, I would highly recommend simply getting a beautifier and a text editor with code folding. Personally I use notepad++, but I'm sure there's dozens of others with those simple capabilities.

Ironically, I'm on SO right now as a break from an XML file I'm working on with broken indentation. The original developer had the indentation working well (it's in a non standard language for which the libraries are poor) but subsequent developers have given it... less care than it deserves.

Comment: Well, I'm really asking specifically about alternative syntaxes. My question was partly motivated by coming across one such syntax, and my wondering whether it's a standard or not. I don't have an example, but it had this form:

    element
      -attribute "attribute value" -anotherattribute "and its value" "the content of the element"

All double quotes required. I find the apposition of two quoted strings a bit tough on the eyes, but otherwise it works.

(OIC, no formatting in comments...)

Comment: I see. I thought you were specifically asking about easier ways for humans to maintain XML files using a text editor. Mostly because of the line "This isn't about alternatives to XML, like JSON, but simply easier ways for humans to maintain XML files using a text editor". :-) And personally I would find folding xml to be easier to work with than an alternate syntax.

Comment: ok, replace "using a text editor" with "using any text editor" :)